# How were Donald Trump's 2015 comments about Muslim immigrants unconstitutional?

Tags: united-states, constitution, president, immigration, donald-trump

A [2015 campaign press release](https://web.archive.org/web/20151207230751/https://www.donaldjtrump.com/press-releases/donald-j.-trump-statement-on-preventing-muslim-immigration) from Donald Trump, back then the leading contender to become the Republican party’s nominee for US presidential candidate, called to ban Muslims from entering the United States:

> "Donald J. Trump is calling for a total and complete shutdown of Muslims entering the United States until our country's representatives can figure out what is going on."

White House press secretary Josh Earnest responded to this during an official White House press briefing:

> "The Trump campaign, for months now, has had a dustbin of history-like quality to it, from the vacuous sloganeering to the outright lies to even the fake hair — the whole carnival-barker routine [...] It’s morally reprehensible, it runs counter to the Constitution and it has consequences for our national security [...] The fact is what Donald Trump said yesterday disqualifies him from serving as president"

Was Josh Earnest's statement that denying entry to the United States based solely on religion would be against the constitution correct?

And was Josh Earnest in his function as a representative of the White House allowed to criticize party nominee contenders that way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The premise of your question was faulty prior to the edit; the Constitution protects the rights of every individual within the jurisdiction of these United States from infringement by the Federal, State, and Local Governments. There is not a prerequisite that an individual be a citizen to have their rights protected, though there may be a few more hoops for them to go through to exercise those rights. Yes, there are certain rights that are restricted to citizens, like voting.

Most of the 'unConstitutional' determinations about Trumps statements are based on an obtuse expansion of his statements beyond what he said. In referencing actions taken by FDR to limit the immigration of Germans, Italians, and Japanese, he opened himself up to a connection to the Japanese internment. Past that, there are current Treaties and other associated agreements between these US and other nations regarding immigration policies. It would take an act of Congress, adjusting legislation, to modify who is allowed into these United States.

On the 'right to disqualify,' they can't. They are just calling his character into question giving his prejudicial statements. The administration however, through Josh Earnest, is free to discredit or judge Trumps statements publicly. There is a legitimate concern that his expressed desire of keeping out all muslims can be used as a propaganda or recruiting device. However, the shortcoming of that concern is that there is already a stated intention to kill us; hiding from that reality just leaves these United States unprepared to provide a defense.

Comment: Also, FDR's actions were taken against citizens of other states. Trump could be accused of citing as precedence the only WWII head of state who targeted citizens of many states but only one religion...

Comment: @DrunkCynic you are correct to say the Constitution doesn't apply only to citizens. To back up your point, it is worth quoting the specific language from the 14th Amendment that says "No state shall deny any _person_ the equal protection of the laws." It does not say citizen, but person.

Comment: -1 for "there is a stated intention to kill us". **A minority** of Muslims have stated such intention, yet the measure proposed targets all of them. It is like proposing to jail all white people because Timothy McVeigh and his buddies were all white.

Comment: @SJuan76 - at what level of risk would you be willing to eat at Chipotle, knowing that a minority of them have given their customers food poisoning?

Comment: @DrunkCynic depends. How many people will die if I don't eat there?

Comment: @DJohnM: To clarify, FDR's actions were against American citizens. He imprisoned citizens whose ethnic background matched the countries the USA was at war with. Many of those people were born in the USA and so were natural-born citizens.

Comment: @Avi it is not necessary to look at the 14th amendment; constitutional protections for non-citizens go back at least to the bill of rights, which also use the words "person" and "people" rather than "citizen."

Comment: "It would take an act of Congress, adjusting legislation, to modify who is allowed into these United States." Technically true, but Congress has already enacted such a provision which delegates that authority to the President. [8 USC 1182(f)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1182#f) grants authority to the President to deny entry to any class of non-U.S. nationals or even all non-U.S. nationals to the U.S. for however long "he shall deem necessary" whenever he deems such entry to be "detrimental to the interests of the United States." This authority was invoked by Trump on Friday.

Comment: @SJuan76 While I don't agree with the entry ban, your reasoning is kind of faulty there. There's a really big difference between when the minority we're talking about is 49.9% vs. 10% vs. 0.000001%. Timothy McVeigh constituted roughly 0.0000005% of white Americans. Also, from a legal perspective, banning entry vs. throwing people in jail are very different and incomparable things. Again, I'm not necessarily disagreeing with your conclusion, just the reasoning.

Comment: @jalynn2 at the risk of going on a tangent, FDR's actions were against Japanese-Americans specifically, not German-Americans and not Italian-Americans.

Comment: @reirab your reasoning is also flawed. Timothy McVeigh was used as a single illustrative example of terrorism committed by white Americans. Unless you count all the white terrorists you are comparing apples and oranges (or rather, apples against a single orange).

Comment: @JDoe My point was just that basing a comparison on the basis that they're both minorities of the population is false equivalence. For the comparison to be meaningful, you'd need data to show that the percentage of white Americans who are terrorist sympathizers is similar to that of whatever group you're comparing against. The fact that they're both minorities doesn't mean they're comparable.

Comment: @reirab what would sympathizers have to do with anything?

Comment: It appears the analysis in the middle paragraph has since been proven completely wrong by later events.

Comment: @T.E.D. The constitutional judgments of his statements prior to the election and the constitutional findings of his actions after being sworn in are independent.

Comment: @reirab: It should be noted that [Congress's delegation of authority to the president is almost certainly invalid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondelegation_doctrine).

Comment: @Sean The article you linked says you're wrong about that (as does the U.S. Supreme Court.) The vast majority of executive powers exist only due to Congressional statutory authorization. Even the courts inferior to the Supreme Court exist only because they are authorized statutorily by Congress.

Answer (score 5):

A new answer since this question has taken on renewed importance.

There is a misconception here. Banning a whole community is *not* Unconstitutional. The Constitution only applies to US citizens, and to non-citizens *after* they have passed the immigration checkpoint. One can certainly disagree whether this is fair and whether it *should* be done this way, but this is simply the way it is, affirmed by many Supreme Court decisions.

As a matter of fact, the US had laws banning people from certain countries in the past, and they were upheld by the Supreme Court. The Chinese Exclusion Act, which was in force from 1884 to 1921, comes to mind. Also the post-1921 quota system that heavily favored European immigrants.

However, today, banning a community based on country of origin is a violation of the Immigration and Nationality Act of 1965. [8 U.S. Code § 1152 (a)(1)(A)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1152) spells it out (emphasis mine):

> Except as specifically provided in paragraph (2) and in sections
>   1101(a)(27), 1151(b)(2)(A)(i), and 1153 of this title, no person shall
>   receive any preference or priority or be discriminated against in the
>   issuance of an immigrant visa because of the person’s **race**, sex,
>   **nationality**, **place of birth**, or **place of residence**.

Comment: This is true, but in this case, the argument is usually about whether or not the ban is about particular group/nationality, or if it's based on religion. If it's based on religion, that *is* seen as unconstitutional.

Comment: @blip in the end, it may take a Supreme Court decision to decide. But the way I understand the legal situation according to current precedent (and I am not a lawyer), currently *nothing* done to non-citizens prior to or at the inspection station would be unconstitutional (although it can be constrained by other laws, such as the INA). It is probably just repulsive to how Americans perceive themselves and their Constitution.

Comment: Yea, the law can be a little fuzzy at times. Intent plays a part in it all as well. A court will be the one to decide at some point, of course.

Comment: A ban on Muslim immigration affects the rights of citizens and domestic institutions. For example, if a citizen applies for permission for their spouse to come to the United States and that application is denied on the basis of their spouse's religion, that could be argued to violate the citizen's rights. For an extreme example to show how the rule can't be what you say, consider an official policy that the government will kill the non-citizen relatives of anyone who criticizes the government.